# Sqlite3 prepare statement, step statement crash in ios

Tags: ios, sqlite

I am working on an application, in that we are using sqlite3... This is first time i am using sqlite3... i created global db connection.. that means i open database only one time then i use that database connection object in my application... not closed anyware.. my issue is some times i am getting crash in prepare statment and step statement... Issue is database already performing update/insert....

```
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory , NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDir = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    return [documentsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:kFilename];
    if (sqlite3_open_v2([[self dataFilePath] UTF8String], &database, SQLITE_OPEN_READWRITE, NULL) != SQLITE_OK) {
    isDbOpen = YES; //global variable to check db is open

}
```

My question how to i check if database is already executing any queries... or any one help me to over come this issue..

Comment: Why do you need that check

Comment: because i am getting crash on prepare statement and step statement....